# Port information for outgoing request php?

Tags: php, port

what is the difference between port (as i get it from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']`) AND THE port infromation we get form `phpinfo();` Because i am developing one site and its facing the problem of not getting content from twitter feeds and youtube and `allow_url_fopen` is also on . now they are asking which port i am using to access this site.

Comment: Which port? `phpinfo()` lists `smtp_port`, `memcache.default_port`, ... . If you see a mismatch between viewing `phpinfo()` in your browser, and reading `$_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]` in your script, that is expected. The remote ports refers to the other side of the TCP connection that was used to request your PHP page.

Comment: so can you tell me which port should i give to hosting support person so i can get feeds from url what i personlly think is port information got from -> $_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]

Answer (score 0):

So you are wondering why your requests to `https://api.twitter.com/whatever` or `http://youtube.com/blablabla` fail.

1. Check your error logs. Have `error_log` log to some non-public log file, set `error_reporting = E_ALL` (don't forget to set `display_errors = Off` in production).
2. Check the return values, look up their meaning in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual).
3. If it turns out that one outgoing port is blocked, know what port is used for the resources. `https` uses TCP port 443. `http` uses port 80. See also [Wikipedia - List of TCP and UDP port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

`$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` is completely unrelated to this issue. Why not explain the support person your problem? They should be able to figure out pretty quickly what port needs to be opened.